# Moved GE fridge to a new home

Tags: refrigerator

I moved a GE fridge 7 years old to a new home 20 miles from old home, I set the fridge in the basement as a second fridge, when turning the fridge on it triggers the smoke detector alarm, any reason why ? Is there a fix ? Thanks

Comment: Is the refrigerator generating smoke? Have you tried disabling the alarm and bringing in another alarm to test against the refrigerator?

Comment: Never heard of a fridge setting off a smoke alarm.  A stove/oven can do it, but do not laugh at the cook.  Are they on the same circuit?

Comment: Is the smoke alarm battery op or wired, and if the latter, is it on the same circuit as the fridge?

Answer (score 0):

Some electric appliances generate noise (EMI) or transients on the electric line. That can trigger some sensitive devices (more often GFCI than smoke detector). If it's just electrical noise causing the issue, there's no danger, and the issue can be resolved.

To check if it's EMI, temporarily use a **heavy-duty** (rated 15 amps or more) extension cord to connect the fridge to another outlet, one **not** on the same circuit as the smoke detector. If the detector stops false-triggering, it's just EMI that needs to be remedied.

You can use a [snubber circuit](https://automationforum.co/what-is-snubber-circuit-and-how-does-it-work/) or a mains noise filter such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XWHPXVG) to reduce EMI. Be sure that you would be able to return the device if it doesn't work.

On the other hand, if the extension cord is neither a hazard nor objectionable, you could run the refrigerator using that other circuit.